# Implementing a Date Function in AGE

Tags: apache-age

I am trying to implement date() function in AGE, but C doesn't have an in-build date function that I can use. I am considering utilizing the `age_timestamp()` function and converting its output to date format. However, I have been unable to find the specific algorithm for this conversion.

```
Datum age_date(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
      agtype time = age_timestamp()
      
      // Program Logic
}
```

Are there any alternative methods that can provide the desired date functionality in AGE.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage PostgreSQL's built-in `localtime` function to achieve this functionality.

Actually date() function is already implemented in AGE ([GDBMS_cypher](https://github.com/apache/age/pull/698/commits/d625d4e99abef272eb3208a1424d0a7e01657799)). Here is how it was implemented:

```
Datum date(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[11];
    sprintf(s, "%04d-%02d-%02d", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text(s));
}
```

You can change this code to return an agtype.

```
Datum age_date(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    agtype_value agtv;
    agtype *agt;

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[11];
    sprintf(s, "%04d-%02d-%02d", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);
    
    agtv.type = AGTV_STRING;
    agtv.val.string.len = check_string_length(strlen(s));
    agtv.val.string.val = s;
    agt = agtype_value_to_agtype(&agtv);

    return AGTYPE_P_GET_DATUM(agt);
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `localtime()` function from `time.h`

```
#include <time.h>

Datum age_date(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);

    char date_string[11];
    sprintf(date_string, "%04d-%02d-%02d", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);

    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text(date_string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find local date and time using `localtime` which is available in `time.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    printf("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS = %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since date() function already implemented in [AGE](https://github.com/apache/age/pull/698/commits/d625d4e99abef272eb3208a1424d0a7e01657799). We can built this another way using help of **#include "utils/datetime.h"**. which is-:

```
#include "utils/datetime.h"

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(age_date);

Datum age_date(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    int64 timestamp = GetCurrentTimestamp();

    /* Convert the timestamp to a DateADT */
    DateADT date = timestamp / USECS_PER_DAY + POSTGRES_EPOCH_JDATE;

    PG_RETURN_DATEADT(date);
}
```

In here **GetCurrentTimestamp()** function is available from **utils/datetime.h** header. **USECS_PER_DAY** and **POSTGRES_EPOCH_JDATE** both are  constant defined in the PostgreSQL source code that represents the number of microseconds in a day and  Julian date corresponding to the PostgreSQL epoch.

Answer (score -2):

`time.h` has a function `localtime()`. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t currTime;
    time(&currTime);

    struct tm* localTime = localtime(&currTime);

    int year = localTime->tm_year + 1900;
    int month = localTime->tm_mon + 1;
    int day = localTime->tm_mday;

    printf("Local Time: %d-%02d-%02d\n", year, month, day);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this add to the earlier answers?